# ajax filter and select

Tags: jquery, jquery-ajax

I am wanting to run an ajax command to return just one column from one row. The first query returns all rows, but just with the Title column. The second query returns just one row, but with all columns.

How do I modify it to return just one column, from one row?

```
    $.ajax({
       url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project%20List')/Items?$select=Title&amp;$filter=Title%20Eq%20%27ABC%27", //THE ENDPOINT
       method: "GET",                                                      
       headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
       success: function (data) {
            console.log('hhh '+data.d.results) //RESULTS HERE!!
       }
    });

  $.ajax({
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project%20List')/Items?$filter=Title eq 'ABC'&amp;$select=Title", //THE ENDPOINT
   method: "GET",                                                      
   headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
   success: function (data) {
        console.log('kkk '+data.d.results) //RESULTS HERE!!
   }
});
```

Interestingly, if I put the following line into Chrome, I do just get the one row, one column.

```
<snip>_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project%20List')/Items?$Select=Title&$Filter=Title%20eq%20%27ABC%27
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
$.ajax({
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project%20List')/Items?$filter=Title eq 'ABC'&$select=Title", //THE ENDPOINT
   method: "GET",                                                      
   headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
   success: function (data) {
        console.log('kkk '+data.d.results) //RESULTS HERE!!
   }
});
```